# Symfony Doctrine ORM - Column name does not exist when running migration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

I am working on the Doctrine ORM (2.4.8, I know, it's old I cannot do anything about it right now) part of the code (Symfony 3 again, I'm aware it's old). I need many-to-many relation here because multiple Countries might be listed in multiple LineItems.
The primary key of the Country table is iso3 and I would not like to modify it.

Here is the field that should contain the countries:

```
class LineItem
{
...
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CampaignBundle\...\Country", inversedBy="iso3")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     * name="lineitem_country_filter",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="iso3")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lineitem_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $countryFilter;
...}
```

Here is a part of the Country class:

```
class Country
{...
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="iso3", type="string", length=10, unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LineItem", mappedBy="countryFilter")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Region", mappedBy="country")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $iso3;
...}
```

When I try to run `symfony console d:m:diff` I get this issue:

```
In SchemaTool.php line 648:
Column name 'iso3' referenced for relation from CampaignBundle\...\LineItem towards CampaignBundle\...\Country does not exist.
```

I have no idea how to solve it. Just for a small clarification, I'm a junior dev in a small company ;)

Comment: From what I understand you need unidirectional manyToMany relation. Please check it in doc https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.4/reference/association-mapping.html and update your code accordingly. Also, you in your Country Entity relationship you did not provide full name space for LineItem. And there is nothing about CountryNA (which mentioned in error msg), where it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to – Nuryagdy Mustapayev, it works now. I've changed the LineItem code as follows:

```
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CampaignBundle\...\Country")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="lineitem_country_filter",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="lineitem_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="iso3")})
```

Removed the `@ORM\ManyToMany` from `Country` part, because as Nuryagdy mentioned it's unidirectional relation.

The CountryNA was my mistake, I forget to remove 'NA' so it's more readable, now it's fixed.